# how to prevent browser's autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've implemeted jquery datepicker on a textbox and datepicker is poping up with browser's default autocomplete that's confusing for the usera. I've tried autocomplete="off" but it's not working.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you have.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML for the textbox element, add `autocomplete=off`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: I think this solution is for Firefox, it ain't working with chrome.

Comment: Sadly in my case it's not even working with firefox.

Comment: This is a standard part of the HTML5 specification. It will work in any browser that supports that specification. It does work in Chrome 17+ and FF 4+

Comment: But it isnt working

Comment: @TaufeekAhmadKhan if you post your code people can help troubleshoot the problem.